# Move Back to previous controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am using the following function for moving back to previous controller

```
- (void) onBack:(id) sender {
   [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

It is working fine in normal situation but the problem arises when I goto more than 1 viewcontroller.

If I move from Viewcontroller1 to ViewController2 then to Viewcontroller3

From Viewcontroller3 if I press the backbutton, it comes to ViewController2, again if I goto ViewController3 and come back to Viewcontroller2. From ViewController2 if I press back button it has to goto ViewController1 instead it is going to ViewController3

Can any help me how to solve this issue.

I am using following code for moving from one Controller to another (just one sample)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NotificationEditProfile
     object:nil
     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
     HUEditProfileViewController *editHUProfileViewController = [[HUEditProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditProfileView" bundle:nil];
     editHUProfileViewController.isLocationEnabled = true;
     [_navigationController pushViewController:editHUProfileViewController animated:NO];
                                              }];
```

Comment: if you want to go back to 1, you can use: popToRootViewControllerAnimated from any.

Comment: That is certainly not possible, you must be changing navigation stack somewhere in between please double check your implementation.

Comment: are your embed with navigation controller

Comment: Khurram Shehzad: Actually it is working if I go from ViewController1 -> ViewController2->ViewController3... when I press back button from Viewcontroller3 it goes to ViewController2 then when I press back button Viewcontroller2 it goes to Viewcontroller1. But the problem arises when second time when I go from ViewController2 to ViewController3 then only the problem starts (I guess its something to do with Number of Viewcontrollers) but not sure

Comment: show ur view hierarchy on ur storybaord, or show how your are moving between view controllers.

Comment: I am not using StoryBoard

Comment: then show the code of how you are moving between VC

Comment: Teja Nandamuri: I had included the code for calling ViewController

Comment: you need to provide detailed descriptiopn of your issue. Pls show the code that shows VC2 from VC1 and VC3 from VC2.

Comment: For VC1 to VC2 to VC3 I am using pushViewController only

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to explaining how to navigation controller works.

It's maintain navigation stack. let's assume there is three ViewContoller like A,B and C.

initially naviagtion stack is empty so top of stack is empty.

when you set A as rootviewController then it's become top of stack. Top of stack always visible on screen or window.

Now if you push B on A then B became top of stack so B is visible on main screen. So now your navigation stack is like A -> B (top).

Now if you push C then stack will be like this A->B->C (top). So, c is in front of you or on main screen.

If now you pop view controller that means you are `removing` top of stack from your navigation stack. so if you call popViewController then C is removed from the stack so your stack is now A->B(top).

Again push C then A->B->C (top)

Again pop then A->B(top)

Again pop then A(top).

So top of stack is always visible and earlier vc remains in stack. but when you pop then top is removed from stack.

So, if you go to C from B and press back then come to B again is fine but when you press back from B then it's come to A because you already remove C from stack and B is top of stack and you are going to removing it so only A remains on stack.

This is the flow of navigation controller.

Hope you will get help :)